# Home page opens to bottom

Tags: html, code

Every time my home page loads it will scroll to the bottom of the page. How do I fix it?

> https://donvonapparel.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your theme footer Newsletter form instantiate `VarienForm` for form validation. Please change below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-detail', ' Text Here...');
    //]]>
    </script>
```

With:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-detail');
    //]]>
    </script>
```

You page scroll to bottom due to second parameter of `VarienForm`, it try to focus form element on loading.

Answer (score 0):

Your homepage is scrolling to the bottom of the page because the newsletter gain focus on it's input field

Try changing your code to (setting second option to false)

```
var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-detail', false);
```